# jwplayer play linked video

Tags: jwplayer

HTML/JS:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 page-header ">
            <h1>
                Videos
            </h1>   
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12" id="vid">
            video will go here.
      </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jwplayer("vid").setup({
        flashplayer: "javascript/jwplayer/player.swf",
        file: "d2rlstwcyqj5nz.cloudfront.net/01.03.12.mp4",
        height: 270,
        width: 480
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open d2rlstwcyqj5nz.cloudfront.net/01.03.12.mp4 directly in the browser, the video gets downloaded. But in the code above, the player does not find the video. Why?

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with selecting the delivery method of 'download' on the distribution. As described here -http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/49/using-cloudfront, I have been testing with streaming delivery method and that works great as long as the html page is not tested locally. Locally, the loading spinning wheel appears and the video never plays. But if I upload the html itself to an s3 bucket and open it in the browser from there, streaming works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try including `http://` at the beginning.